# java how to deploy only changed .class file to remote server via sftp after Build Project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I think it can divide as three steps:

1. list only changed .class
2. upload them to sftp server
3. restart server

I can do 2. and 3. with `wagon-maven-plugin`, but I don't know how to do 1. with the `wagon-maven-plugin`.

some background:
This is a very old project(spring 3.x), plain spring web project without any maven stuff and running on tomcat server.

Our current deploy way is:

1. build project with `IntelliJ IDEA`
2. manually upload changed .class files to server via sftp
3. restart tomcat server with ./shutdown.sh and ./start.sh script.

I want improve the deploy way, because it's error-prone when we choose which files need to upload and I can't just upload all the class because it may overwrite other people's work.

I know we should just use jar/war format, but because history reason we can't.

Comment: Probably you can check this link. https://github.com/mojohaus/wagon-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/it/ftp-download/pom.xml

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how a pom.xml file solve my problem?

Comment: You can check the usage of `maven-wagon-plugin` in that link not as whole pom.xml.

Comment: ok, but I still don't understand, `maven-wagon-plugin` can list only changed .class?

Comment: Have you considered using [Tomcat](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html) Remote run configuration and [configure ftp deployment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html#05aea08a) type there?

Comment: @Andrey yes, but I think it need jmx feature right? my server doesn't have that feature. And I didn't find out how it work, doesn't it upload all .class instead just changed .class?